# Force kernel to generate core dump file in ELF64

Tags: gdb, coredump

I'm using AARCH64 ILP32 user space buildroot, but AARCH64 LP64 kernel.

On exception, kernel is generating core dump file in ELF-32 format.

Is there a way to force kernel to generate core file in ELF64?

My kernel is built with the following bin_fmt configurations:

```
\#

\# Userspace binary formats

\#

CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y

CONFIG_ELFCORE=y

\# CONFIG_CORE_DUMP_DEFAULT_ELF_HEADERS is not set

CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y

\# CONFIG_HAVE_AOUT is not set

\# CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC is not set

CONFIG_COREDUMP=y

CONFIG_COMPAT=y

CONFIG_ARM64_ILP32=y

CONFIG_SYSVIPC_COMPAT=y

\# CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_KDUMP is not set
```